# Syntax for comparison expression in Simple case expression in Oracle DB SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, antlr, antlr4

I am trying to make a parser for Oracle SQL select statement which include CASE statement

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/img/case_expression.gif

And the oracle reference listed that the simple case expression can be expressed in
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/img/simple_case_expression.gif

But i cannot find the comparison expression everywhere in the reference, does anyone have a clue where is it and how it looks like?

Answer (score 0):

<s>I believe it's the same as the `condition` defined here:</s>

```
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/conditions001.htm#SQLRF52101
```

which means it can be several kinds of things, requiring all of chapter 7 of the manual to explain them. And most of them in turn can include arbitrary expressions (that's all of chapter 6, plus chapter 5 for function calls) and even subqueries (so all of chapter 9 too). For eaxmple this is a "simple case statement" in action:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT /* anything that can go in a select statement might be here */) > 0
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
  END
FROM DUAL
```

And in the nested query you can have all kinds of hard-to-parse things. Basically if you want to parse a `CASE` expression the way Oracle would parse it, you're in trouble. There's no way to avoid the need to parse the rest of Oracle SQL.

If you limit yourself to standard SQL (and maybe ban subqueries) you have a better chance of finishing the project.

OK, first answer was exactly the opposite of the truth. `comparison_expr` is an `expr` that will be compared to the `expr` that comes right after the `CASE`.

Comment: Does the comparison condition equal the comparison expression?
It seems it is not the case as we can put 
case abc when 1 then blah blah blah

Comment: That would be a `searched_case_expression`, not a `simple_case_expression`.

Comment: I believe it is not a searched_case_expression as there is a field after CASE keyword
where the syntax of searched_case_expression is like this (from oracle)
CASE
  WHEN boolean_expression THEN result_value ;
[ WHEN boolean_expression THEN result_value ; ]... 
[ ELSE result_value ; ]
END CASE ;

Comment: You're right. I got the whole thing backwards. `comparison_expr` is an expression to be compared to the CASE expression.

Comment: So is that the comparison_expr only the simple_expression or it is just an expression but oracle reference wrongly put it as "comparison_expr"?